# What is cause of friction?

Tags: friction

I know two definitions of [friction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction), one says because of irregularities and other says because of the electrostatic force between atoms, but I don't which one is more relevant.

Comment: The relevance depends on what you're studying. If you're studying the physical interaction between macroscopic objects then surface irregularities are relevant. If you are studying the microscopic interactions between the two surfaces then the electrostatic force if more relevant.